# Multiple Super( ) for overloading super class constructor

Tags: java, constructor, overloading, super

```
class Time
{
    public static void main (String args[])
    {
       Son obj = new Son();
    }
}
class Father            // Super Class
{
    Father(int x, int y)            // parameterized constructor 
    {
        int a = x;
        int b = y;
        System.out.println("Super Class Constructor a = "+a);  
        System.out.println("Super Class Constructor b = "+b); 
    }
    Father(int z)            // parameterized constructor 
    {
        int d = z;
        System.out.println("Super Class Constructor d = "+d);  
    }
}
class Son extends Father    // Sub Class
{
    Son()                   // default constructor 
    {
        super(100);
        super(10, 20);      // Problem is here

        int c = 200;
        System.out.println("Sub Class Constructor c = "+c);
    }
}
```

My question is can we use multiple super ( ) in subclass constructor as i want to initialize two super class Parameterized constructor. If it is not possible then how can i do this?

Comment: Short answer is no.  In your last sentence, where you ask "how can I do this", what is it that you actually want to do?  Your `Father` constructors are very strange, in that they set local variables but don't use them.

Comment: Build only 1 constructor Father (int x, int y, int z) {
}

Comment: @DavidWallace I was just trying to use two super( ) in one constructor. This is not allowed in Java we can not use two super ( ) in one constructor because super ( ) must be the first statement. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My polemic answer is you don’t want to do that (feel free to challenge me). You want to design you superclass (`Father`) in such a way that it only takes one super constructor call to construct and initialize it so that it is ready for use.

In your example you haven’t got any fields in `Father`, so any of your constructors should be good enough for that. if you’re happy with the constructors you have but still want the output from both, there are a couple of options. First, you may add a three-arg constructor `Father(int x, int y, int z)` as Nghia Do suggested in a comment. You don’t need to delete the other two constructors if you prefer to have all three. Second, you may put in a method call instead of the second super call, and write a method in `Father` to print the message and do what other work you require. For the sake of code reuse, you ought to have the two-arg constructor call the same method rather than having the code duplicated.

Think what would happen if you had a class with two constructors and you needed to call both — if that was allowed. This would be a tricky bug waiting to happen. There would always be a risk that someone forgot to call both. You’d end up with some half-constructed object, and no one would know when something would go wrong when you used it.And when that happened, it would be far from obvious that it was due to the forgotten second constructor call. As I said, you don’t want that. The rule that Java always calls exactly one super constructor is a good one.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is simply wrong. A constructor in Java has to always call **exactly** one super class constructor. There is no such thing as writing down super() twice in the same constructor.

In other words: the **very** first statement in a constructor is a call to a super-class constructor. If you don't put such a call there, the compiler will insert a call to *super()* behind the covers.

In that sense: when you are a beginner, and the compiler gives you an error message; the thing to do: turn to a good book or [online resource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html).